# moving menu from horizontal to vertical as user scrolls?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menubar

I'm currently running Wordpress with Twitter Bootstrap, bhtml5 boiler plate, css3  and latest jQuery.

My main navigation menu is currently fixed to the top of the page in a horizontal position.

How do I go about making the menu move to a vertical position as the user scrolls down the page( preferably with a nice transition effect)?

If some one could point me in the direction of a jQuery/Mootools/etc doc that would help me do this it would be a great help.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $("#nav").addClass("horizontal");
} else {
    $("#nav").removeClass("horizontal");
}
//console.log($(window).height());
});
```

basicly the oppisite of this and adding a transition effect:[http://jsfiddle.net/bbYZS/2/]

Comment: It will be not an easy answer, but I would sugegst to debug this page: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html I have just found it, and that is the way I try to learn stuff. I hope it will help. Of course the method used there is not good for you.

Comment: not quite what i'm looking for i want the whole menu to reposition it's self from a horizontal menu to a vertical menu this is just a fixed float the css is changing when the page is scrolled....

Comment: I'm sorry they did not do it in a way it would be helpfull for you. I have seen divs 'sticking' to the bottom and slowly 'sliding out' so that should not be css any more. Let me check something.

Comment: kk. maybe this. There are two gadgets there on the http://rp.pl page. When you open any of the articles, and you scroll down, you will see something that will pop appear at the bottom of the page. I truly hope it will be something to help you!

Comment: Link to the article: http://www.rp.pl/artykul/16,945754-Mucha-zostaje--Klopoty-tez.html. Scroll down. It will slide in from the right.

Comment: I suppose i could have the main menu disappear adn the side menu scroll in it's definetly and idea...thank you grzegoz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after working with jQuery for a while I have managed to do this myself: 
I am using jQuery UI switchClass() [docs](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/) and jquery animate [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJj4z/1/)
here is the exact javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// This seems smoother but "animate" is buggy when applied to scrollTop so uncomment this if you want to see the smoother button function work
//    var toggleStatetwo = true;
//        $('.clickthis').on('click', function() {
//        if(toggleStatetwo) {
//        $(".nav").animate({"width": "81px"},"slow");
//        } else {
//        $(".nav").animate({"width": "801px"},"slow");
//        }
//        toggleStatetwo = !toggleStatetwo;
//       });
var toggleStatetwo = true;
$('.clickthis').on('click', function () {
    if (toggleStatetwo) {
        $(".nav").switchClass("nav", "nav_vert", 800);
    } else {
        $(".nav_vert").switchClass("nav_vert", "nav", 800);
    }
    toggleStatetwo = !toggleStatetwo;
});
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $(".nav").switchClass("nav", "nav_vert", 800);
    } else {
        $(".nav_vert").switchClass("nav_vert", "nav", 800);
    }
    //console.log($(window).height());
});
```

});

Enjoy who ever needs it and vote this up :D